# React Native Networking

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

I need help I get this error Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1. I have tried looking through the docs and stack, still no luck. There is something wrong with the response?

```
'use strict'
import React,{Component} from 'react'
import {View,StyleSheet,Image,Text,TouchableOpacity,TextInput} from 'react-native'
import StatusBarBackground from './StatusBarBackground'
import TextBoxLayout from './loginComponents/textInput'
import Button from './loginComponents/button'
import IconIm from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'



class SignUp extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {name: '',
                    password:'',
                    username:''};
    }
    _navigateToProfile(){
      this.props.navigator.push({
        indent:'Profile'
      })
    }
    _updateServer(){
      console.log("HEY ",this.state.name)
      console.log( JSON.stringify({
        email: this.state.name,
        username: this.state.username,
        password:this.state.password
      }));
      fetch('http://localhost:3000/endpoint/', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
              "email": this.state.username,
              "username": this.state.username,
              "password":this.state.password
          })
      }).then((response)=>response.json())
      .then((responseJson)=>{
        console.log(responseJson);
        return responseJson
      }) .catch((error) => { console.error(error); });
    }
    render(){
        return(

          <View style={styles.container}>
          <StatusBarBackground/>
              <View style={styles.top} >
                  <Text style={[styles.login,styles.lineHeight]}>Sign up</Text>
                  <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}><Text style={styles.login}>SIGN UP WITH FACEBOOK</Text></TouchableOpacity>
                  <Text style={styles.login}>or</Text>
              </View>

              <View style={[styles.bot]}>

                <View style={styles.sizer}>
                  <View style = {styles.textInput}>
                      <View style={[styles.ImgCon,styles.space]}>
                        <IconIm name='ios-mail' color="#dae0ea" size={25} style={styles.img}/>
                      </View>
                      <TextInput style={[styles.textbla,styles.space]} paceholderTextColor='white' placeholder='Enter Email'
                      onChangeText={(name) => {
                        this.setState({name})
                      }}/>
                  </View>
                </View>

                <View style={styles.sizer}>
                <View style = {styles.textInput}>
                    <View style={[styles.ImgCon,styles.space]}>
                      <IconIm name='ios-person' color="#dae0ea" size={25} style={styles.img}/>
                    </View>
                    <TextInput style={[styles.textbla,styles.space]} paceholderTextColor='white' placeholder='Enter Username'
                    onChangeText={(username) => {
                      this.setState({username})
                    }}/>
                </View>

                </View>

                <View style={styles.sizer}>
                <View style = {styles.textInput}>
                    <View style={[styles.ImgCon,styles.space]}>
                      <IconIm name='ios-lock' color="#dae0ea" size={25} style={styles.img}/>
                    </View>
                    <TextInput style={[styles.textbla,styles.space]} paceholderTextColor='white' placeholder='Enter Password'
                    onChangeText={(password) => {
                      this.setState({password})
                    }}/>
                </View>

                </View>

                  <TouchableOpacity onPress ={()=>this._updateServer()}>
                    <Button text='signup'/>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this._navigateToProfile()}>
                <Text style ={{color:'white'}}>CLICK MEE</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>

            </View>

        )
      }
    }
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({

      container:{
        flex:1,
        alignItems:'center',
        backgroundColor: '#181c26'
      },
      top:{
        flex:2,
        justifyContent:'space-between',
        flexDirection:'column',
        alignItems:'center',

      },
      sizer:{width:300,height:50},
      bot:{
        flex:7,
        flexDirection:'column',
        alignItems:'center'


      },
      lineHeight:{
        lineHeight:60
      },
      button:{
        width:300,
        height:50,
        backgroundColor:'#3B5998',
        overflow:'hidden',
        borderRadius:25,
        alignItems:'center',
        justifyContent:'center'
      },
      login:{
        fontSize:20,fontWeight:'500',color:"#f7f7f7"
        ,fontFamily:'AvenirNextCondensed-Heavy'
      },
      input:{
        flexDirection:'row',
        justifyContent:'center',
        borderRadius:10,
        overflow:'hidden'


      },
      imgCon:{

        alignItems:'center',
        justifyContent:'center',
        backgroundColor:'blue',
        width:200
      },
      textInput:{
        flex:7,
        backgroundColor:'#353535'
      },
      textInput:{
        flex:1,
        flexDirection:'row',
        backgroundColor:'#353535',
        borderRadius:5,
        overflow:'hidden'
      },
      space:{
        justifyContent:'center',
        alignItems:'center'
      },
      ImgCon:{
        flex:2

      },
      textbla:{
        flex:9,
        color:'white'

      }
    })
    module.exports = SignUp
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks that way. The promise pipeline is failing in the `json()` step, as it finds a character ('o') in a position that is invalid according to the JSON format rules. Try checking first if `response.ok` is true, then check whether `response.status` and `response.statusText` give you a hint on what can be the problem. Also, you can replace `json()` with `text()` to check the response text data that is trying to be parsed.